# basic jquery problem

Tags: jquery, richfaces

I just went thru w3schools tutorial for JQuery. I am trying ot write a function in seam/richfaces app. I have a search icon and onclick of the search icon, I want to toggle certain fields in UI. But nothing happens and i dont see any errors in firebug. Please help.

```
<rich:dataTable id="acctListTbl" value="#{accounts}" var="account" width="100%">
    <rich:column>
   <f:facet name="header">
    <h:panelGroup>
         <h:graphicImage id="srchIcon" value="/images/search_icon.png" 
                             styleClass="search-icon"/> 
            <h:outputText value="Action" />
        </h:panelGroup>
   </f:facet>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("#acctListTbl:srchIcon").click(function(){
      jQuery('.search-field').toggle(); 
  });
 });
 </script>
```

Here is the html. As user914670 pointed out, there is no jquery handler added to my search icon rendering. So what is wrong?

```
 <div id="j_id12:acctListTbl:j_id31header:sortDiv">
    <img id="j_id12:acctListTbl:srchIcon" class="search-icon"  
         src="/xxxx/images/search_icon.png">
         Action
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you show the rendered HTML rather than the server-side code that generates it?

Comment: I don't see element with the class .search-field

Comment: I would not recommend using w3schools as a jQuery resource. http://w3fools.com

Comment: though not shown search field exists and works fine with javascript. Add onclick="toggleSearchFields();" in search icon and write javascript function toggleSearchFields(){ jQuery('.search-field').toggle(); }

Comment: @user238021: You may need to do a little more debugging.  You don't see any errors in FireBug, that's fine.  But what do you see?  When the document loads, is jQuery matching `#acctListTbl:srchIcon` on any elements to bind the event?  If so, when the event is fired, does `.search-field` match any elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){   
      jQuery(".search-icon").click(function(){       
              jQuery('.search-field').toggle();    
       });  
});
```

or if you love ids you could do

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){   
      jQuery("[id$=srchIcon]").click(function(){       
              jQuery('.search-field').toggle();    
       });  
});
```

$= means that ends with

^= means starts with

*= means contains

Also I would check out [SelectorGadget](http://www.selectorgadget.com/) for use in Firefox. Its really good for finding the selector statement you need to get a certain element.

One last thing that I do to make sure that I am in side an event is put an alert statement that goes off in side the function to let me know that my select statement is correct.

Answer (score 2):

No class `.search-field` is present in your markup

Comment: .search-field is avaliable in xhtml. If i replace Jquery with onclick="toggleSearchFields();" and write javascript, things work great. function toggleSearchFields(){ jQuery('.search-field').toggle(); }

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that when you follow a class or an id with a colon, you are looking for and element that has a specific property and srchIcon is not a property.

I believe what you meant to do with **jQuery('#acctListTbl:srchIcon')** is the following:
**jQuery('#acctListTbl #srchIcon)**

That says the target is an element with an ID of srchIcon inside of an element with an ID of acctList.

That could be part of your problem.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery("#acctListTbl:srchIcon")` only needs to be `jQuery("#srchIcon")`

Because id's are unique on a page, they don't need to be qualified. Also an easy way to tell if Jquery is even creating the event handler is to look at your rendered code and see if your image has a `JQuery="{some random numbers}"` tag.

Comment: Event handler is not getting created. Any idea why?

Comment: Can you post your rendered html of the image?

Comment: <th><div id="j_id12:acctListTbl:j_id31header:sortDiv"><img id="j_id12:acctListTbl:srchIcon" src="/xxxx/images/search_icon.png" class="search-icon" />Action</div></th>

Comment: AAh it needs to be jQuery('#j_id12:acctListTbl:srchIcon') then. I am not sure how jQuery will treat the colons though. If that fails you can also try jQuery('.search-icon') if that is the only place that class is used